# Finding *two* html tags with Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

I need to pull out the content out of two paragraph tags and break it with a `<br />` tag. The input is like so

```
<p>
Yay
</p>
<p>
StackOverFlow
</p>
```

It needs to be like

```
<p>
Yay <br />
StackOverflow
</p>
```

What I have so far is `<p><?php  preg_match('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/', $content, $match); echo($match[1])."..."; ?></p>` Which pulls the first paragraph tag only:

```
<p>
Yay...
</p>
```

Also, is it possible to set a character limit? A max of 40 characters for example from both of the paragraphs or would I have to use `substr`?

Thanks!

So it turned out to be:

```
<?php $content = preg_replace('/<\/p>\s*<p>/', '<br/>', $content);  echo substr("$content",0,180)."..."; ?>
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you need to do something like this? This is a travesty.

Comment: Apart from not using Regex for HTML matching, I suggest that you don't use `.*` constructs, those are greedy and while they may do what you expect them to do in small samples, they will try and "eat" much more in cases where the matching end pattern is found again later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Given that you want to collapse:

```
<p>Yay</p><p>StackOverFlow</p>
```

into:

```
<p>Yay<br />StackOverflow</p>
```

Then just substitute instances of `</p><p>` for `<br>`: `preg_replace('/<\/p>\s*<p>/', '<br/>', $input)`.

---

In general, however, note that use of regular expressions for this kind of complex parsing is fraught with peril. More succinctly:

> "Some people, when faced with a problem, think, 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."
>   -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: maybe that should be `</p>\s*<p>`, it looks like there might be a newline between them

Comment: See what I meant about being fraught with peril? ;) Thanks for the catch, Kip.

Comment: This assumes he wants to replace EVERY </p><p> with a <br>. Is that the case?

Comment: For that particular instance, yes. Since it is a small chunk of content, that's perfectly feasible.

Answer (score 6):

Do yourself a favor and use a HTML parser (`DOMDocument::loadHTML` for example). It's easier and less fragile.

Answer (score 0):

My advice, Regex can only go so far. See one of my posts here:
[Extracting text fragment from a HTML body (in .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236915/extracting-text-fragment-from-a-html-body-in-net)

It has string truncation regex too.